# regex fetching first words from a dash separated line

Tags: ruby

I have an array that contains elements in this form and shape:

{john-mary-peter-car, house-dog, mouse-mice, etc}   etc so items separated by a dash and each item separated by a comma (as you would expect in an array of course). I am trying to map through the array using the regular expression to fetch only the first word of every element, (like, john,house, mouse) but all I m getting is a roster of 0.

Here is the code (I first fetch the file and shove it into the array):

```
    linesdb = Array.new
    File.open('mylist.txt').each { |line| linesdb << line }
    puts( linesdb.map{|a| a=~ /^(.+?)-/})
```

the regex has to be right, but I think somewhere in the rest of the syntax is not ok,. The regex says, fetch at the beginning whatever there is until the dash in a non-greedy fashion, so like dont continue fetching beyond the dash.

thank you

UPDATE

The comment of Mark Thomas did have the brightest most elegant code, but he did not post it as an answer and cant give the points to it. Then there was an alternative solution, which I honored.

Yet here is my own stuff based on Mark Thomas

```
linesdb = Array.new
File.open('medicamentos-lista.txt').each { |line| linesdb << line.split('-').first }
puts linesdb
```

Comment: `john-mary-peter-car, house-dog, mouse-mice` is a `line` ?

Comment: no, until the comma only, after each comma, a new line

Comment: `puts line.split('-').first`

Comment: You need a clearer example of the input you're getting. That seems to be the source of the problem

Comment: @Mark Thomas. Your code is the solution. Brilliant. Please post it as such so that I can honor it/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use `scan` like this:

```
 File.open('mylist.txt').each { |line| linesdb << line.scan(/^(.+?)-/)[0][0] }
```

and then (to get the array like result):

```
print linesdb
```

or

```
puts linesdb
```

Comment: hyphenbash. While the comment of Mark Thomas did have the brightest solution, he did not post it as answer only as a comment and I cant  give points to it. You took the work of posting the whole thing and although I finally posted my own solution based on Mark Thomas bright code, I cant give points to myself, cant give points to Thomas, so I give them to you. And I give the finger to whoever the Va-stard is that downvoted my very good question.

Comment: Thanks :). my solution was based on purely regex and pushing the filtered result to the array. I also agree @mark-thomas solution is neater. You could give his comment a thumbs up though, not sure how it would affect his rating.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is entirely based on Mark Thomas input and ALL the credit goes to him, but he put it as a comment and I cant use it to give him points.

```
linesdb = Array.new
File.open('medicamentos-lista.txt').each { |line| linesdb << line.split('-').first }
puts linesdb
```

Also I am sure the solution of Hyphenbash would have worked 100%.

With regards, to whoever has voted down my question, I give him the finger in return.